# htaccess fake file path

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have a WordPress site, let’s say it’s on http://awesome.site. On this site I’ve created a page with url awesome.site/page.

Now I wish to include a physical file named “file.txt” so it’s url would be awesome.site/page/file.txt. How to do that?

Of course, if I create a folder /page and place a file.txt inside it – WordPress wouldn’t show the content at all. My physical file.txt is currently located inside /stuff directory – current full path is: awesome.site/stuff/file.txt

Comment: What server do you use? Usually, if you create `/page/file.txt` using `ftp`, this file will be accessible from web if your server doesn't forbid it.

Comment: It's a shared server.

What I actually want is to create custom service worker for each WordPress subpage.

So I need to have file to seem to be under each page dynamically. Just like in example.